# Creating own Linux distribution - Kernel Panic

Tags: linux, kernel, init, initramfs-tools

Im currently creating a very specialized Linux distribution, that should just perform one single, very easy task.

http://www.aclevername.com/articles/linux-xilinx-tutorial/minimalist-initramfs.html

What I have done, is created the initramfs according to the instructions. The only thing I have not done, is compiled the kernel. Instead I used a already compiled one, a generic kernel.

I manage to boot it, but when it has unpacked the initramfs, it kernel panics with that it failed to start init.

If I move the compiled init script out of the root folder (/), to a subfolder, it will instead say it failed to load the root filesystem, which means I somewhat managed to verify that it does actually load the initramfs correctly.

The init script is statically compiled, and on the local system, it executes successfully. To further debug the problem, I copied sh (/bin/sh) from the local system as /init in the initramfs, to see if it was something wrong with my "hello World" init script. But same result with /bin/sh as init.

Any ideas how to further debug the problem?

Comment: I think the initramfs is distro specific. Create your own!

Comment: @lporSircer Its the initramfs I created. I suppose you mean "kernel"? right?

Comment: Stock kernel should be bootable on with a correct initramfs. Check your initramfs again. And don't forget: what howto you linked is 6 years old!